# Making debugger work with zend / phpstorm on Mac OS

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm running zend server on my local machine.  I'm trying to install a debugger using this guide

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-zend-debugger.html

i get down to the step about "zend debugger should appear in phpinfo"
and it does (see screenshot)

[image]

then it gets weird.  it says go to file > settings > php

but i dont have a settings... i have a default settings. so i go there > php

i choose my php version from interpreter, and hit the ...

I either get **Debugger: Not Installed** or a **Debugger:** with nothing following

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: *"then it gets weird. it says go to file > settings > php"* That's for Windows/Linux and for PhpStorm v8.0.1 and older. For Mac and current versions it's `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`

Comment: Double check what php.ini file you are using -- on Mac/Linux you may have 2 different files for CLI and web environments.

Comment: @LazyOne good catch.  I found it there in preferences.  I add my php file, and i end up with "Debugger: Not Installed" ..  if i run phpinfo i see that i'm using this /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini ..  thats the one i've edited.  Do I need to choose that in phpstorm somewhere?

Comment: 1) Just run `php -i` in console (make sure that it uses your configured PHP Interpreter). The config file listed there is the one that you need to edit. It may be different to what is used if you run `phpinfo()` via browser. 2) Make sure that debugger is reported in phpinfo output's header 3) Make sure that you have only one debugger engine activated -- having both xdebug and ZendDebugger most likely will not work.

Comment: ok so i noticted this on top of the output:

"Zend Debugger requires Zend Engine API version 220100525.
The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is newer."

crap....  what do i do? i can't downgrade zend engine.

Comment: Well ... as I see it: 1) upgrade/downgrade your PHP 2) or Zend Debugger 3) or just use Xdebug